# Customize Log text with postsharp

Tags: postsharp, loggly

I am testing using Postsharp to log entry and exit to my methods (log4net). The problem I am having is that I want the log message to be a json object, not what you seem to get by default which is:

Entering: MyClass.MyMethod(params)

I want some thing like
{"Action":"Entering", "Class":"MyClass", "Method":"MyMethod" etc}

This is because I am using loggly to interpret the logs and with a json log message it is so much better for filtering, searching etc.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible as PostSharp relies on one of supported backends (log4net, enterprise library, nlog) and minimizes computational cost of logging the message itself.

You would need to leverage the backend to transform the message into the format you need, which would mean implementing custom `ForwardingAppender` in case of log4net.

That being said, we are now working on a redesign of the log aspect, which would enable you to do such transformations more easily. You can take a look at PostSharp's roadmap [here](https://www.postsharp.net/support/roadmap).

Comment: I think I have worked around it by using custom derived fields in loggly.